# How to deal with can not find module in node.js

Tags: node.js

When I run my server file then it shows me an error.

Error: Cannot find module 'pug'

```
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at new View (/home/pi/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
at Function.render (/home/pi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
at ServerResponse.render (/home/pi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
at /home/pi/mapserver/routes/files.js:81:9
at /home/pi/mapserver/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
at replenish (/home/pi/mapserver/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1006:25)
```

Comment: Did you add `pug` to your dependencies, like `npm i pug`?

Comment: as @pzaenger says try re-installing the `pug` module. It's also probably a good a idea to do `npm i --save pug` so it stays in your `package.json`. Next time you want to install dependencies you can just do `npm install`

Comment: Yes,i have  + pug@2.0.3

Comment: As it stands right now, your question is difficult to answer as all we have is an error message with no context: the code that's throwing the error would be useful. This is a useful resource for learning how to ask a good question that helps people help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution that has worked for me several times:

- Make sure you have all your dependencies (including the right version of PUG module) listed in your package.json
- Remove your node_modules file (rm -r node_modules)
- Reinstall all your dependencies: npm install / npm i

Comment: Once I Remove it and reinstalled it it worked.thank you.